# How to rename list of Object[] in a JList

Tags: java, json, swing, gson, jlist

beginner here.

I am working an app to display information to users about different companies. I get the info via API in different formats, some have fields which makes deserialization easier, and other responses contain only a List of Columns, and a List> of Rows. I recreated a minimal JFrame to show my problem:

[image]

My question is about the latter. I iterate through the list and add every row to the JList, and once selected, the information contained within that list is displayed in JLabels.

My questions is instead of having the whole list contained within each Object displayed in the JList, is there a way to have only certain values from each list displayed? For example, Date and Person? I do not have a class with getters and setters because the API response does not have fields.

Here is the code for the window:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Window extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
public JList list1;
private JButton buttonSearch;
private JTextField searchField;
public JLabel nameValue;
public JLabel roleValue;
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

public String passingValue;
public String passingValue2;


public Window() {
    buttonSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                clearList();

                URL apiURL = new URL("http://api.cloudquote.io/sage/getInsiderActions.json? 
     T=APIKEYHERE&symbol=GOOG");

                String readLine = null;

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) apiURL.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(readLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

                    String jsonResponse = response.toString();

                    Deserializer actions = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, Deserializer.class);

                    Object[] newList = actions.getRows().toArray();

                    for (Object object : newList) {
                        listModel.addElement(object);
                    }

                    list1.setModel(listModel);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    list1.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            nameValue.setText("");
            roleValue.setText("");

            String stringTest = String.valueOf(list1.getSelectedValue());
            List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringTest.split(",")));

            passingValue = myList.get(0);
            passingValue2 = myList.get(2);


            nameValue.setText(passingValue);
            roleValue.setText(passingValue2);
        }
    });
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
    frame.setContentPane(new Window().contentPane);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 500));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


 }

 public void clearList() {
    list1.removeAll();
 }


}
```

Here is my Deserialization Class to parse the JSON response:

```
   import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
   import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

   import java.util.List;

  public class Deserializer {

  @SerializedName("rows")
   @Expose
   private List<List<String>> rows = null;
  @SerializedName("columns")
  @Expose
  private List<String> columns = null;

  public List<List<String>> getRows() {
    return rows;
 }

  public void setRows(List<List<String>> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
 }

  public List<String> getColumns() {
    return columns;
  }

  public void setColumns(List<String> columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Deserializer{" +
            "rows=" + rows +
            '}';
    }
  }
```

And finally here is what the JSON response looks like:

```
{
"rows": [
[
  "CapitalG LP",
  1678225,
  "",
  "C",
  "2020-02-13",
  830211,
  0,
  "A",
  "I",
  830211,
  "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1535527/000089924320004527/xslF345X03/doc4.xml"
]],
"columns": [
  "Insider",
  "CIK",
  "Role",
  "Transaction Code",
  "Transaction Date",
  "Shares",
  "Price Range",
  "Aquired/Disposal",
  "D/I Own",
  "Total Holdings",
  "Filing"
]
}
```

What would be the best approach to solving this? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to display the data in a `JTable` (not a JList).

The JSON response gives the values for:

1. the header and
2. each row of data.

The code to create the `JTable` would be something like:

```
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

for (String columnName; action.getColumns())
{
    columnNames.add( columnName );
}

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

for (List<String> listRow; action.getRows())
{
    String[] row = listRow.toArray( new String[listRow.size()] );
    model.addRow( row );
}

JTable table = new JTable( model );
frame.add( new JScrollPane( table ) );
```

Comment: Thanks @camickr, that is how I displayed at first. But I thought a list of the transactions would've been an interesting way of organizing data. I guess I will stick to JTables !

Comment: It is a list of transactions. The difference is you can actually read the transaction data without having to click on a specific row first. You could easily change the table to only display a few columns and then if you click on a row, display the rest of the data for a row if you wish. In any case glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer, by clicking, on the checkmark,  so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I accepted sorry man, yeah I will make a custom table. Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy if you **create a DTO** and then override the toString method of the class.

Example

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CatDTO {

    private String id;
    private String url;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getId() + " -> " + getUrl();
    }

}
```

[Attached ConsumeApiRestDemo Java Swing with JList](https://github.com/delacruzcruzdiegoandres/ConsumeApiRestDemo)

Comment: Unless I am missing something here, I can't use getters and setters because there are no fields for me to point to in the JSON response. Is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: Sorry. In the example use the lombok library that automatically creates the getters, setters and toString. See https://projectlombok.org for Java.  It is also valid to create the getters and setters manually

Comment: I understand, but you need fields to point to to create getters and setters, no? Look at the JSON response and the format it has, it's a list of rows and columns, not in the format: {"id": "123", "url": "http://etc"..} hence me saying I can't creat getters and setters for a specific field like getID(). Anyways, thanks for the help